# crash when returning bool from ccPhysicsCollisionBegin in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, physics

Hey I have ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve and ccPhysicsCollisionSeparate functions working in swift but when I implement ccPhysicsCollisionBegin I get a crash when I run.

```
func ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(pair: CCPhysicsCollisionPair!, typeA nodeA: CCNode!, typeB nodeB: CCNode!) -> Bool {
        NSLog("collision test begin")
        return true
}
```

I googled, and found people changed the return value to ObjCBool which I tried and got this error on compile,

/Users/macuser/Documents/spritetest2.spritebuilder/Battle.swift:121:10: Objective-C method 'ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:typeA:typeB:' provided by method 'ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(*:typeA:typeB:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(*:typeA:typeB:)' in protocol 'CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the error is understandable because you now have two methods with the same name and the same parameters but returning different values - how would the compiler now which one you actually want to execute? What error did you get before changing anything of the default signature?

Comment: Some fatal error that said "expecting Bool" which I assume is the obj-c bool.  I can get the exact error later.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the return type to `ObjCBool` is the correct fix for the crash.

The compile error you are now receiving is a different error.  You need to replace `typeA` and `typeB` in the declaration with the `Collision type`, set in SpriteBuilder, for the two nodes that you want to detect a collision for.

[image]

For example if I have a node with a `Collision type` of `level` and another with `hero`, the function would be defined as:

```
func ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(pair: CCPhysicsCollisionPair!, level nodeA: CCNode!, hero nodeB: CCNode!) -> ObjCBool {
    ...
}
```